# Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\bin\java" Invalid directory name

Tags: java, ioexception, processbuilder

I have a "slave" program and a "master" program. The master program is executing the slave, and then, the slave is executing another program (an external program). It makes possible the reboot of the master program without ending external programs.
But this is my problem :
I can run the slave program from the master program using processbuilder, but the slave can't find java with his processbuilder.
Made I a mistake ?

I've already tried to change the slave execute directory and the master executing directory. But no changes.

Master's Processbuilder

```java
        final String javaCmd = System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "bin" + File.separator + "java";
        final List<String> bpArgs = new ArrayList<>();
        bpArgs.add(javaCmd);
        bpArgs.add("-jar");
        bpArgs.add(gameServer.getSlavePath());
        bpArgs.add("servers/" + gameServer.getName().toLowerCase() + "/" + serverName);
        bpArgs.add(gameServerVersion.executable);
        final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(bpArgs);
        pb.directory(new File("").getAbsoluteFile()); // Run into the current directory

        try {
            final Process p = pb.start();
            <...>
        } catch (IOException e) {
            <...>
        }
```

Slave's Processbuilder

```java
        final String javaCmd = System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "bin" + File.separator + "java";
        List<String> bpArgs = new ArrayList<>();
        bpArgs.add(javaCmd);
        // TODO: Add RAM args
        // Game args
        bpArgs.add("-Dcom.mojang.eula.agree=true");
        bpArgs.add("-DIReallyKnowWhatIAmDoingThisUpdate=true");
        bpArgs.add("-jar");
        bpArgs.add(args[1]); // executable JAR file
        log("Starting with arguments >>> " + bpArgs.toString());
        final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(bpArgs);
        pb.directory(new File("servers/minecraft/" + args[0])); // Run into the game directory

        try {
            p = pb.start();
            <...>
            p.waitFor();
            log("Server stopped with exit code " + p.exitValue());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            <...>
        } catch (IOException e) {
            <...>
        }
```

This is my actual output :

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\bin\java" (in directory "servers\minecraft\servers\minecraft\Hellow"): CreateProcess error=267, Invalid directory name
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at eu.gameinbox.svm.slave.MinecraftSlave.main(MinecraftSlave.java:33)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=267, Invalid directory name
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 1 more
```

I just want the slave's processbuilder to work.
Thanks for your future help !

Comment: Does the directory "servers\minecraft\servers\minecraft\Hellow" exist relative to your current execution path?

Comment: Yeah ! It is relative servers folder is in the execution folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I've found the problem !**
Thanks to VivekRatanSinha !

The server was in servers/minecraft/Hellow not in server/minecraft/Hellow/minecraft

In my slave's processbuilder I used

```
pb.directory(new File("servers/minecraft/" + args[0]));
```

But the args 0 was the total path not the server name !

I just changed it to

```
pb.directory(new File(args[0]));
```

And now it works fine.

Comment: I am glad to be of assistance :)